# Search entire df in R in a way similar to is.na()?

Tags: r, dataframe

Is there a way to search an entire `dataframe` for a value without having to loop over each column? Similar to the `is.na()` function?

For example, I'm writing a function for a large `dataframe` and trying to find how many values in the `dataframe` are the string "NA". Is there a more efficient way than using a `for-loop`, such as:

```
for(i in 1:3)
  print(sum(df[,i]=="NA"))
```

Essentially, something like `is.na()` that could be applied to other values, in order to search the entire `dataframe` instead of each `vector`.

Comment: `sum(df == "NA")`.

Comment: Thanks.. that was indeed what I was looking for! I'm a beginner.. should I delete this post since too obvious?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df <- data.frame(a = c(1,"NA"), b = c("NA",3))   
sum(df == "NA")

# [1] 2
```